# Why cell tag returns the same value in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tags

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I add tags to my cells as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:people = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! people

    cell.fullName.text = self.fullNames[indexPath.row]

    cell.viewProfile.tag = indexPath.row
    temp = cell.viewProfile.tag

    cell.viewProfile.addTarget(self, action: "viewProfile:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

where

```
var temp = 0
```

on the top, under the class declaration.

And when I try later:

```
func viewProfile(sender: UIButton) {
    print(temp)
}
```

it returns me 2, the same value on each time. Why? What I do wrong?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? tags are almost certainly not the correct approach to take...

Comment: How many cell have you got in the table view? If you have three the temp will be 2 because every time you load the cell you override the temp.

Comment: @Wain I just putted button on UITableViewCell and when I click on it, I want to know `indexPath.row` of this button clicked cell through `addTarget`. I searched a lot and found the solution with tags.

Comment: so it's better to pass the cell a view model it can use to edit things, or a controller object that it can pass its config data to. in any case the tag on the class in related to the last cell that was updated and doesn't really mean anythign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get the index of the button that is clicked. Then try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:people = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! people

    cell.fullName.text = self.fullNames[indexPath.row]

    cell.viewProfile.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.viewProfile.addTarget(self, action: "viewProfile:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func viewProfile(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Index : \(sender.tag)")
}
```

No need of temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath to show the indexPath.row. You are always printing the same value because in the case you run the cellForRowAtIndexPath it's always run until the last cell that display on your view. So you always get the same value of temp var.